Safetycli detailed output in json
I want to get safety scan data in json format. This works, but doesn't give me CVE or severity details:
safety scan --debug --json --stage production --output json > ./scan-results/safety_output.json 2>&1 || true

Regular output, in json format
This spits out the details I want, but not in JSON format.
safety scan --debug --json --stage production --detailed-output json > ./scan-results/safety_output.json 2>&1 || true

Detailed output - not json

Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

I suspect you need to parse the JSON, get the vulnerability ID, then do another lookup to get the corresponding CVE information.

What does this have to do with Python or programming? You're just asking how to use a preexisting tool.
